# Android FirebaseDatabase recyclerview null exception for a single variable(userid)

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I want to show user Profile image for each post. I wrote a code for this but i am getting an error.

[image]

```
//Here is error---

FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.example.serhat.blog, PID: 5614                                                                           java.lang.NullPointerException: Can't pass null for argument 'pathString' in child() 
at com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference.child(Unknown Source)
at com.example.serhat.blog.MainActivity$2.populateViewHolder(MainActivity.java:95)
at com.example.serhat.blog.MainActivity$2.populateViewHolder(MainActivity.java:80)
```

---

```
//Here is my code
 //Profile image//
                mDatabaseUsers.child(model.getUserid()).child("image").addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                        String image = dataSnapshot.getValue(String.class);
                        viewHolder.setProfileImage(MainActivity.this,image);
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

                    }
                });

//Here is blog class 

    private String title,description,image,uid,username,senddate;


    public Blog()

    {

    }

    public Blog(String title, String description, String image, String uid, String username,String senddate,String profileimageUri) {
        this.title = title;
        this.description = description;
        this.image = image;
        this.uid = uid;
        this.username = username;
        this.senddate=senddate;
    }
    public String getUserid() {
        return uid;
    }
    public void setUserid(String uid) {
        this.uid = uid;
    }
```

Solved. Thanks for your answers. The problem is my database stracture in firebase i changed 'uid' to 'userid' and problem solved.

The problem is method names and the domain name in the database are not the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems `model.getUserid()` in `mDatabaseUsers.child(model.getUserid())` is `null` which causes the NullPointerException.

Why it's null is hard to tell with the code you've provided, but you should be able to debug it.